# Reference to Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise

This code works:

```js
Promise.all([Promise.resolve(1)])
```

However, this code does not:

```js
const f = Promise.all

f([Promise.resolve(1)])
```

The second piece of code throws the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Promise.all called on non-object`.

Why can't I assign the function Promise.all to a variable and use it as normal?

Answer (score 2):

Because that's what [the spec requires](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise.all).

```
1. Let C be the this value.
2. Let promiseCapability be ? NewPromiseCapability(C).
3. Let promiseResolve be Completion(GetPromiseResolve(C)).
...
```

> The **all** function requires its **this** value to be a constructor function that supports the parameter conventions of the Promise constructor.

Your current code is not calling the function as part of an object (that is, `f` is a standalone identifier), so the resulting `this` is either the global object or `undefined`, depending on whether you're in strict mode or not - either way, the above requirement is not fulfilled.

If you bind the function to Promise, it'll work.

```
const f = Promise.all.bind(Promise);
```